# set rate-limits for specific apis in kubernetes nginx

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, nginx-ingress

I am currently using [nginx-ingress-controller](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx) in my eks-cluster.
I want to set rate-limits for only specific apis like `/healthz` like mentioned [here](https://www.nginx.com/blog/rate-limiting-nginx/#Configuring-Basic-Rate-Limiting) and not only all my APIs.

Is there a way i can do it?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For separate specific you can make another ingress resource

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/limit-rps: "15"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "true"
  labels:
    name: ingress
  name: ingress
spec:
  rules:
  - host: healthz.example.io
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: hello
          servicePort: 80
        path: /healthz
```

While you can make one ingress resource for other API, without rate limit setup

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "true"
  labels:
    name: ingress-2
  name: ingress-2
spec:
  rules:
  - host: healthz.example.io
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: hello
          servicePort: 80
        path: /data
      - backend:
          serviceName: hello
          servicePort: 80
        path: /api
```

Comment: So, I shall create two kubernetes ingress resources with different names. One to restrict api-rate limit for `/healthz` api and the second one for all the other apis ?

Comment: yes you can give it try

Comment: Tried this . however when i test it `ab -c 100 -n 100 http://<mydomain>/healthz` using apache utils. it shows 
```Complete requests:      100
Failed requests:        0
Non-2xx responses:      100``` . 
So, how to check if the annotations are correctly applied. i see the rate limit and stuff in nginx-controller's `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf`

Comment: could going through `/` path if it's there did you tried removing that and keeping one ingress and tested ? plus nginx follow leaky bucket rate limiting so make sure and test with keeping single ingress.

Comment: actually increased the number to 500 and i could see some 503 requests